# php custom zip file

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, zip

Currently have an html form with 6 checkboxes, each one giving a value of 0 or 1 depending on whether it is checked or not. Each checkbox refers to a seperate pdf on the site. What is the best way to turn these checkbox values into a zip file?
The zip file will then be passed, as an attachment, to an emailing script, which has already been written

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want to know how to create the zip-file and tell us this has already been written. So what is your question then?

Comment: No the email form to send the zip file has been written. But the actual creation of the zip file has not been written yet. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If each of your checkbox refers to a PDF file, why don't you put the name of this pdf file in the chechbox name attribute? Like this, once the form is post, you'll get all the name of the PDF required and you zip them using  [ziparchive class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) for example.